# what does the reportRoot: getSharePointActivityUserDetail User Principal Name (returns as GUID) mean?

Tags: azure, graph, sharepoint-online, usage-statistics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

Who to get user info from the User Principal Name(GUID) returns in getSharePointActivityUserDetail  api

[Result sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zigpf.png)

Comment: Hi Agha. I suggest you to rephrase your title and rewrite the question in the text to have something more comprehensible. Please note that it's always better to past the logs in a code block in place of insert a screen shoot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand (the question and the doc), the GUID is a global and unique ID for all SharePoint users.

You can found a PowerShell command [here](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/get-sharepoint-list-guid-powershell/) that could help you to get the user names from the guid:

```bsh
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

Get-SPSite http://win-pfcp2dgt8di/sites/EnjoySharePoint/ | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} |?{$_.ID –eq "B13CC473-6187-4478-A0DD-853E83AA6F9D"} |ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
```